# Error when deserializing my string to object in C#

Tags: c#, serialization

I'm trying to deserialize my string here

> LicenseName=10&StartDate=7%2F20%2F2016&EndDate=09%2F28%2F2016

using this method

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        ConsumedUserLicense jsonObject = serializer.Deserialize<ConsumedUserLicense>(licenseDetails);
```

to this object

```
public class ConsumedUserLicense
{
    public int LicenseId { get; set; }
    public string LicenseName { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

but I'm getting an error that says

> "Invalid JSON primitive: LicenseName.

Comment: That string is not valid JSON. It's not even *invalid* JSON. Where did you get it from? It's a query string, isn't it? Come on, fess up. We're all friends here.

Comment: I used $('#form).serialize() in Javascript. What should I have done?

Comment: Yeah, that method returns a properly encoded query string (as in a URL), not JSON. There's no direct way to serialize a form to JSON in JS out of the box, but [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1184667/424129) might do it. I haven't tested it, mind you, and right now they're howling at me to fill out some idiotic form for human resources.

Comment: ok, so how do I deserialize a query string in c#???

Comment: a) use json instead. b) paste that exact question into Google and click on the StackOverflow links at the top of the page until you see one that works. I gotta run, they'll screw up my dental coverage and I'll look like Shane MacGowan.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON-String is not a correct JSON-String. Try to copy-paste it in a JSON validator to check it out: [JSON Formatter and Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).

From json.org:

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs. An object begins with { (left brace) and ends with } (right brace). Each name is followed by : (colon) and the name/value pairs are separated by , (comma).

See also: [json.org](http://json.org)